# Reading mysql database in android returns null values

Tags: php, android, mysql

I would like to read data from by mysql database in an android application. I'm using the following php script.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db_name);
$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM `Item`';
$result = array();

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
   echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    array_push($result,array(
      'id'=>$row['id'],
      'title'=>$row['title'],
      'description'=>$row['description']
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

When debugging my android application, I could see that I got the following response.

[image]

It seems like the array was successfully returned from php to the android application, but the values are null. So I would assume that there is an issue in php code.

In addition, it's interesting that the correct number of entries was returned. My database has currently two entries, and also two entries were returned.. but with null values.

Comment: What happens when you request the PHP file directly?

Comment: Are 'id', 'title', and 'description' the exact column names in the 'Item' table?

Comment: @PatrickQ - Yes, these are the exact column names in the "Item" table.

Comment: @user3783243 - What exactly do you mean by "requesting the file directly"?

Comment: `localhost/file.php` or however you host your site. Take android out of the equation and does the issue reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution for the null values.

While pushing the data to the array I had to differ between the data type of the database table columns. In my case, the column "id" has the data type INTEGER. Therefore, I could pass the data into the array using `'id'=>$row[0]`. The other two columns (title and description) have the data type VARCHAR. Therefore, I had to pass the data using `'title'=>"$row[1]"`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
   array_push($result,array(
     'id'=>$row[0],
     'title'=>"$row[1]",
     'description'=>"$row[2]"
   ));
```

}

Using this, the correct values from the database table are now available in the response.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#111208 ...also unless you have modified the default behavior, fetch_array() uses `MYSQLI_BOTH` which means your associatives keys should have worked else you were hiding details from us.  We love to see a `var_export($row);` inside your resultset loop.

Answer (score 0):

If this was my task, I would:

1. not be sending complete error messages in the response (I am going to assume that you only included this detail to show that you performed basic debugging).
2. use object oriented syntax because it is more brief.
3. use `fetch_all()` because you are merely converting the result set array to an array of associative arrays for processing on another layer.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

> As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single
>   step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as
>   mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the
>   result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you
>   will need a looping construct that will further impact performance.
>   **For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those
>   situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer
>   for processing.**

Recommended Code:

```
if (!$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name)) {
    $response = "Database Connection Error"; // $con->connect_error
} elseif (!$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `Item`")) {
    $response = "Query Syntax Error";  // check $con->error; because your query failed
} else {
    $response = $con->fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
echo json_encode(["result" => $response]);
```

*note, when there are no rows in the result set, `fetch_all()` returns an empty array.

This snippet not only returns informative information in case of errors, it is concise, it always returns a value for the `result` key, and it is flexible -- no matter if your `Item` table gains/losses column(s), it won't break, everything gets returned.

No loop, no `array_push()`; fully dynamic and clean result set packaging.